# How to Fix NonFunctional X11 Mouse on WSL2

Tags: x11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

UPDATE Oct 12, 2020: I created another Linux user and that user has no problem with the mouse ... for the first login. After that, the new user also did not show a mouse cursor in the X11 server display. That means the problem is specific to the user, not a system configuration issue, and something happens during the first login. What could that be?

I've got 2 Dell XPS 15 laptops, both were just upgraded from WSL1 to WSL2 and both have been upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. One runs the XFCE4 desktop on X11 using VcXsrv just fine, the other displays the XFCE4 desktop but the cursor does not move and the keyboard has no effect on the desktop.

This snippet from `~/.profile` runs the desktop:

```sh
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
#sudo /etc/init.d/dbus start &> /dev/null
startxfce4 &> /dev/null &
```

Both systems use this `config.XLaunch`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XLaunch 
  ClientMode="NoClient" 
  Clipboard="True" 
  ClipboardPrimary="True" 
  DisableAC="True" 
  Display="0" 
  ExtraParams="-swcursor" 
  LocalClient="False" 
  LocalProgram="xcalc" 
  PrivateKey="" 
  RemotePassword="" 
  RemoteProgram="xterm" 
  RemoteHost="" 
  RemoteUser="" 
  Wgl="True" 
  WindowMode="Windowed" 
  XDMCPBroadcast="False" 
  XDMCPHost="" 
  XDMCPIndirect="False" 
  XDMCPTerminate="False"
/>
```

Output of `startxfce4` on the working system is:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
172.26.16.1:0.0

$ which startxfce4
/usr/bin/startxfce4

$ startxfce4
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display 172.26.16.1:0.0
_IceTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.ICE-unix should be set to root
gpg-agent[4211]: WARNING: "--write-env-file" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one

(xfce4-session:4169): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 12:50:45.121: gpg-agent returned no PID in the variables

(xfce4-session:4169): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 12:50:45.124: xfsm_manager_load_session: Something wrong with /home/mslinn/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-172.26.16.1:0, Does it exist? Permissions issue?

(xfwm4:4215): xfwm4-WARNING **: 12:50:45.412: Unsupported GL renderer (Software Rasterizer).

(xfsettingsd:4219): libupower-glib-WARNING **: 12:50:45.534: Couldn't connect to proxy: Could not connect: No such file or directory

(xfsettingsd:4219): libupower-glib-CRITICAL **: 12:50:45.534: up_client_get_lid_is_closed: assertion 'UP_IS_CLIENT (client)' failed

(xfsettingsd:4219): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:50:45.534: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(xfsettingsd:4219): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:50:45.534: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(wrapper-2.0:4233): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:50:45.982: g_file_new_for_path: assertion 'path != NULL' failed

(wrapper-2.0:4233): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:50:45.982: g_file_monitor_file: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed

(wrapper-2.0:4233): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:50:45.982: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(wrapper-2.0:4233): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:50:45.982: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(wrapper-2.0:4233): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:50:45.982: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkToggleButton to a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, but the widget is already inside a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, please remove the widget from its existing container first.

(xfce4-session:4169): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 12:50:46.010: failed to run script: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/pm-is-supported” (No such file or directory)

(xfce4-session:4169): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 12:50:46.013: failed to run script: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/pm-is-supported” (No such file or directory)

(xfce4-session:4169): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 12:50:46.016: failed to run script: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/pm-is-supported” (No such file or directory)

** (wrapper-2.0:4232): WARNING **: 12:50:46.024: Binding 'XF86AudioMicMute' failed!

(wrapper-2.0:4232): pulseaudio-plugin-WARNING **: 12:50:46.024: Could not have grabbed volume control keys. Is another volume control application (xfce4-volumed) running?

(wrapper-2.0:4233): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:50:46.026: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)

(wrapper-2.0:4234): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:50:46.037: Negative content width -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node button, owner XfceArrowButton)

** (xiccd:4258): CRITICAL **: 12:50:46.142: Failed to connect to colord: Could not connect: No such file or directory

** (agent:4267): CRITICAL **: 12:50:46.145: Failed to get connection to system bus: Could not connect: No such file or directory
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

(wrapper-2.0:4232): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:50:46.200: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner PulseaudioButton)

(unity-fallback-mount-helper:4255): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: 12:50:46.282: remote volume monitor with dbus name org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor is not supported

(nm-applet:4279): nm-applet-WARNING **: 12:50:46.378: Error connecting to system D-Bus: Could not connect: No such file or directory

(nm-applet:4279): nm-applet-WARNING **: 12:50:46.379: Could not connect: No such file or directory

(nm-applet:4279): libnm-CRITICAL **: 12:50:46.383: ((libnm/nm-client.c:3905)): assertion '<dropped>' failed

(nm-applet:4279): libnm-CRITICAL **: 12:50:46.389: ((libnm/nm-client.c:3859)): assertion '<dropped>' failed

(nm-applet:4279): libnm-CRITICAL **: 12:50:46.389: ((libnm/nm-client.c:3937)): assertion '<dropped>' failed

(nm-applet:4279): libnm-CRITICAL **: 12:50:46.390: ((libnm/nm-client.c:3986)): assertion '<dropped>' failed

(nm-applet:4279): libnm-CRITICAL **: 12:50:46.390: ((libnm/nm-client.c:4026)): assertion '<dropped>' failed

(nm-applet:4279): libnm-CRITICAL **: 12:50:46.391: ((libnm/nm-client.c:4042)): assertion '<dropped>' failed

(nm-applet:4279): libnm-CRITICAL **: 12:50:46.391: ((libnm/nm-client.c:4080)): assertion '<dropped>' failed

(nm-applet:4279): libnm-CRITICAL **: 12:50:46.391: ((libnm/nm-client.c:4598)): assertion '<dropped>' failed

(nm-applet:4279): libnm-CRITICAL **: 12:50:46.392: ((libnm/nm-client.c:4598)): assertion '<dropped>' failed

(xfdesktop:4235): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: 12:50:46.561: remote volume monitor with dbus name org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor is not supported

** (xfdesktop:4235): WARNING **: 12:50:46.704: Failed to get system bus: Could not connect: No such file or directory
system-config-printer-applet: failed to connect to system D-Bus
[0610/125046.888419:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(930)] Could not load cef_100_percent.pak
[0610/125046.892135:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(939)] Could not load cef_200_percent.pak
[0610/125047.084535:INFO:HandlerRendererProcess.cpp(6)] HandlerRendererProcess created
[0610/125047.090591:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(930)] Could not load cef_100_percent.pak
[0610/125047.090753:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(939)] Could not load cef_200_percent.pak
[0610/125047.507121:INFO:HandlerGUILinux.cpp(141)] Create window
[0610/125047.689543:INFO:HandlerRequest.cpp(20)] OnBeforeBrowse 1 url=qrc://ui/
Jun 10, 2020 12:50:48 PM com.Zc.Za.Zb.Zb.ZAy <clinit>
WARNING: Unable to load JDK7 types (annotations, java.nio.file.Path): no Java7 support added
[0610/125048.702522:INFO:HandlerRendererProcess.cpp(6)] HandlerRendererProcess created
[0610/125048.706700:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(930)] Could not load cef_100_percent.pak
[0610/125048.707000:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(939)] Could not load cef_200_percent.pak
[0610/125048.732046:INFO:HandlerRendererProcess.cpp(6)] HandlerRendererProcess created
[0610/125048.740582:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(930)] Could not load cef_100_percent.pak
[0610/125048.740799:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(939)] Could not load cef_200_percent.pak
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusSignal.Zb(DBusSignal.java:178)
        at org.freedesktop.dbus.Zbt.run(Zbt.java:952)
        at org.freedesktop.dbus.Zwx.run(Zwx.java:197)
Exception in thread "Thread-16" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at org.freedesktop.dbus.DBusSignal.Zb(DBusSignal.java:178)
        at org.freedesktop.dbus.Zbt.run(Zbt.java:952)
        at org.freedesktop.dbus.Zwx.run(Zwx.java:197)
[0610/125049.707698:INFO:HandlerRendererProcess.cpp(15)] Started CEF-render process
[0610/125049.707695:INFO:HandlerRendererProcess.cpp(15)] Started CEF-render process
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SHM" missing on display "172.26.16.1:0.0".
[0610/125050.381922:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Importing icons and logos from Ring UI is deprecated. Please import them from corresponding packages: `@jetbrains/icons` and `@jetbrains/icons`.", source: qrc://ui/index.js (2)
[0610/125050.501390:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Updated model size: 133084", source: qrc://ui/index.js (2)
[0610/125050.516655:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Updated model size: 156335", source: qrc://ui/index.js (2)
[0610/125050.535100:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Updated model size: 156449", source: qrc://ui/index.js (2)
[0610/125050.547730:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Updated model size: 156335", source: qrc://ui/index.js (2)
[0610/125050.566132:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Initial model size: 156414", source: qrc://ui/index.js (2)
[0610/125050.570154:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "`size`, `width` and `height` props are not recommended to use in Ring UI `Icon` component. The intrinsic sizes of SVG icon (`width` and `height` SVG attributes) are used instead.

We strongly recommend to use icons handcrafted for particular sizes. If your icon doesn't exist in the desired size, please ask your designer to draw one. "Responsive" checkmark should be unchecked when exporting icon.'", source: qrc://ui/index.js (2)
[0610/125052.719865:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Updated model size: 205265", source: qrc://ui/index.js (2)
[0610/125106.897010:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Updated model size: 205265", source: qrc://ui/index.js (2)
```

Output of on the non-working system is:

```
$ ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet '
        inet 172.25.63.251  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.25.63.255

$ echo $DISPLAY
172.25.48.1:0.0

$ which startxfce4
/usr/bin/startxfce4

$ startxfce4
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display 172.25.48.1:0.0
gpg-agent[1508]: WARNING: "--write-env-file" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one

(xfce4-session:1482): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 12:50:23.915: gpg-agent returned no PID in the variables

(xfce4-session:1482): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 12:50:23.922: xfsm_manager_load_session: Something wrong with /home/mslinn/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-172.25.48.1:0, Does it exist? Permissions issue?
xfwm4-Message: 12:50:24.247: Another Window Manager (Xfwm4) is already running on screen 172.25.48.1:0.0
xfwm4-Message: 12:50:24.247: To replace the current window manager, try "--replace"

(xfwm4:1510): xfwm4-WARNING **: 12:50:24.247: Could not find a screen to manage, exiting
xfsettingsd-Message: 12:50:24.407: Skipping screen 0, it already has an xsettings manager...

(wrapper-2.0:1530): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:50:24.994: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -1 and height 28

(wrapper-2.0:1530): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:50:24.994: Negative content width -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node border, owner GtkFrame)

(xfce4-session:1482): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 12:50:25.027: failed to run script: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/pm-is-supported” (No such file or directory)

(xfce4-session:1482): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 12:50:25.035: failed to run script: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/pm-is-supported” (No such file or directory)

(xfce4-session:1482): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 12:50:25.045: failed to run script: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/pm-is-supported” (No such file or directory)

(wrapper-2.0:1531): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:50:25.079: Negative content width -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node button, owner XfceArrowButton)
xfsettingsd: Another clipboard manager is already running.

** (xfdesktop:1544): CRITICAL **: 12:50:40.869: xfdesktop: already running, quitting.

** (xiccd:1547): WARNING **: 12:50:40.976: EDID is empty

** (xiccd:1547): CRITICAL **: 12:50:40.989: failed to create colord device: failed to obtain org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device auth
Tracker-Message: 12:50:40.991: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Tracker-Message: 12:50:40.991: Setting priority nice level to 19
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
(uint32 1,)

(nm-applet:1584): nm-applet-WARNING **: 12:50:41.153: NetworkManager is not running
Tracker-Message: 12:50:41.181: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Tracker-Message: 12:50:41.181: Setting priority nice level to 19

** (update-notifier:1634): WARNING **: 12:50:41.190: already running?

** (light-locker:1647): ERROR **: 12:50:41.245: Environment variable XDG_SESSION_PATH not set. Is LightDM running?
```

`DISPLAY` is properly set, I think. XEyes and XTerm work fine ... I only notice a problem with the XFCE4 desktop.

Comment: Did yoy try `rm -fr /tmp/.ICE-unix` before starting `startxfce4` in .profile?

Comment: Just tried it, no effect. BTW, this is the script I am using to test with now: https://gist.github.com/mslinn/1972154269dd498281990cf90d31e8a3

Comment: It is not an answer, but you can try using xrdp instead of VcXsrv. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: This problem might be better expressed as an X11 configuration problem, I think. The choice of client (referred to in the X11 docs as an X server) is probably incidental.